# Is there a way to invert the FN keys lock in a Microsoft designer Bluetooth Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I have this keyboard and the only thing that (for me) is really annoying is that by default the **<kbd>fn</kbd>** keys are enabled. So If I need to reload a page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) I have to press the **<kbd>fn</kbd>**. If a press the **<kbd>fn</kbd>**key alone it enables the F buttons but the light in the **<kbd>fn</kbd>** key is always on (what I suppose is not good for the battery)

Is there a way to invert this behavior? I have tried <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd> and keep <kbd>FN</kbd> pressed 10 seconds without success.

Comment: Light in the fn key? Could you link to exact model you are using?

Comment: "Microsoft designer Bluetooth Keyboard" https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/designer-bluetooth-desktop/7n9-00001

Answer (score 16):

@Ovidiu's method really works. But in fact you don't have to hold for 10 seconds and neither hold `Caps`+`Fn` at the same time! You simply press `Fn` key once and make the led on the key light. That means `Fn` is disabled and you can use F1, F2, ... as usual. To enable `Fn` again, just press the `Fn` key again to turn the light off. Really easy but not that easy to find! ^_-

Comment: For anyone in doubt - there *is* an LED on the Fn Key - I thought maybe this comment was referring to a different model than mine, but it is for the "Microsoft designer Bluetooth Keyboard"

Comment: This isn't great... I use the Fn key a lot, and on keyboards where it acts as a toggle, I tend to often toggle it accidentally, which is really annoying (I have this problem with the Surface Pro keyboard)

Answer (score 9):

Just hold down `Fn` key first, then press `Caps Lock` once, it will be inverted immediately.

Comment: Nope, it does not work.

Comment: The other methods didn't seem to work for me, but this one did! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Caps+Fn works. I really don't know how I did it but trust me, it works. Press Caps key 1st and Fn key immediately after. Hold for 10 seconds and press Fn key again. You will see a small led turning on. That means you can now use your F keys without pressing the Fn key.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + (key) + <kbd>Esc</kbd> works on my Craft Keyboard.  I use it for my work laptop which utilizes a mainframe emulator.  It was a pain to have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + (key) for the terminal emulator functions.

Found the answer in this article:
https://en.code-bude.net/2017/09/02/change-logitech-fn-key-behaviour-without-software/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For the Microsoft Designer Compact Keyboard, you can use the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center app to configure the default Fn state, and I assume it also works for the full-size keyboard. Helpful if you've remapped Capslock to Left Control.

[Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-designer-compact-keyboard-336418e5-eadb-6cdc-9cd9-0016cd1a99e4)

[Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center app download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2)

Comment: Sadly just the compact is listed there

Answer (score 0):

download the Microsoft software for mouse and keyboard to make the change.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2